# how do I solve increased memory usage?

Tags: python, multithreading

When `start_commination` is active in the following functions, there is an increase in memory usage over time. It goes from 150mb to 600mb ram consumption. But I couldn't understand the reason. There are parts with while in other functions, but there was no such situation.
I wonder if the problem is caused by `sio.emit`.

```
def send_audio_e(self):
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(
        format=pyaudio.paInt16,
        channels=self.CHANNELS,
        rate=44100,
        input=True,
        frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK,
    )

    try:
        
            while True:
                if self.is_running:

                    data = stream.read(self.CHUNK)
                    audio_data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)
                   
                    audio_data = audio_data.tobytes()
                    #print(audio_data)
                    try:
                        sio.emit("audio_data", {"audio_data": audio_data})  
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
    except Exception as e:
        print("hata",e)
    finally:
        print("CLOSED")
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        p.terminate()

def start_communication(self):

    threading.Thread(target=self.send_audio_e).start()
```

Comment: Have you tried using any memory profiler? It might tell you the reason.

Comment: no I didn't use it

Answer (score 0):

The increased memory usage you're observing could be due to the continuous accumulation of data in the buffer that is being sent through the sio.emit method. Every time send_audio_e() is invoked and it emits audio_data, it might be accumulating in memory without being released or cleared.

Here are a few steps you can take to address this issue:

- Check the Receiver Side:

Ensure that the server or client receiving the emitted audio_data is handling it properly. If the receiver is accumulating data without clearing it, it could lead to increased memory usage.

- Optimize Data Transmission:

Instead of continuously emitting data, you could try to send data at specific intervals or in chunks, and clear the memory accordingly. For instance, emit data every few seconds or after a certain amount of data has been accumulated.

- Clear or Release Memory:

Explicitly clear or release the memory used for audio_data after emitting it. For example, you might consider setting audio_data = None after emitting it to allow the memory to be garbage collected.

Comment: Is this AI-generated?

Comment: The audio data can be received properly on the receiver side and played back on the loudspeaker. 

I don't think it would be correct to send data every few seconds because I send instantaneous audio.

I tried audio_data = None, but still the memory consumption keeps increasing.
when I left the programme open I saw that it consumed 6gb ram